# Mock Documentum IDfSession using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, documentum

I have the following (simplified) function which I wish to check using JUnit:

```
protected IDfCollection getCollection(IDfSession session) throws DfException{
  IDfQuery dfcQuery = new DfQuery();
  dfcQuery.setDQL(MY_DQL);
  return dfcQuery.execute(session, IDfQuery.READ_QUERY);
}
```

I have successfully tested it using real IDfSession, but I would like do it without connecting to the repository. So I tried to mock empty IDfSession using:

```
IDfSession mockedSession = Mockito.mock(IDfSession.class);
```

But I was given NullPointerException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:182)
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:204)
at com.documentum.fc.internal.util.SoftwareVersion.<init>(SoftwareVersion.java:53)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfQuery.runQuery(DfQuery.java:136)
at com.documentum.fc.client.DfQuery.execute(DfQuery.java:208)
```

Not knowing what actually went wrong (which function of the mocked object returned null which was not expected) I created a simple class implementing IDfSession interface and used code coverage tool to check which function was called. I hoped to mock behavior of the function later using mockito. I seemed to be `getServerVersion` so I changed returned null to real value `"6.5.0.355 SP3P0600 Linux.Oracle"`. Next called function was `getBatchManager` so I mocked returned object here as well. But now I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.model.mock.IDfSessionMocked cannot be cast to com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.ISession
```

I tried to implement ISession interface in the IDfSessionMocked class, but it does not compile, for instance because one of the used types (namely com.documentum.fc.client.impl.session.ISessionListener) is not visible.

Here: http://www.informedconsulting.nl/blog/?p=187 I found information how to do it using powerMock. Another difference is that object is taken directly from session not using IDfQuery.

What should I do?

**Update after comment**

getBatchManager function was mocked and now it returns anonymous inner class object, with all the returned values set to false or 0 depending on the expected returned type. Function isFlushBatchOnQuery has been called according to coverage tool.

Comment: You've got cast exception for ISession to IDfSession object trying to get mocked object for getBatchManager method? I'm not that much experienced with mock object frameworks but I assume you made some beginners mistake. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: My guess is it is no a problem of the object returned by getBatchManager, but more likely, that my mocked class that implements IDfSession interface should implement also ISession, which it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert of Documentum but I think you need a more complex object, you could have a look at this repo https://github.com/ValentinBragaru/dfc-mock

[IDfSessionMock](https://github.com/ValentinBragaru/dfc-mock/blob/master/src/main/java/mock/com/documentum/fc/client/IDfSessionMock.java) is what you need I think.

I hope it helps.